# Что делает if(!el.val())?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

Выполнение вычисления типа !el.val() вернет true если длина строки == 0 и вернет false, если length > 0

Но вопрос именно в том, как jquery это преобразует в длину строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражение `!el.val()` эквивалентно `!(el.val())`. Сначала выполнится el.val(), что вернет строку судя по документации JQuery. Таким образом останется следующее выражение:

```
!expr
```

Оператор `!` - это логический оператор отрицания. А `expr` - в нашем случае строка (String).

Для выполнения логического оператора `!`, его `expr` должен булевого типа. Тогда по спецификации JS должен попытаться автоматически переконвертировать строковый `expr` в `Boolean` для последующего выполнения оператора `!`:

> The ECMAScript language implicitly performs automatic type conversion
> as needed. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-type-conversion

Теперь обратимся к документации JS, как именно `String` конвертируется в `Boolean`:

> If argument is the empty String (its length is zero), return false; otherwise return true. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toboolean

Мы видим, что, если `String` имеет нулевую длину, то он конвертируется в `false`; в противном случае в `true`.

После конвертации у нас остается все то же выражение:

```
!expr
```

Однако `expr` - это уже `Boolean`, в который переконвертирована наша строка.

В итоге: выражение `!expr` будет `true` если строка имела нулевую длину, и `false` в противном случае.

Comment: что такое "унарный тип"?

Comment: Извиняюсь, должно быть "унарным выражением"...

Comment: А это что значит? :)

Comment: Выражение которое принимает унарный оператор в качестве аргумента. Просто в документации у них имеется термин "UnaryExpression". А унарный оператор - оператор имеющий только один операнд.

Comment: Если по спецификации смотреть - унарное выражение - это почти любое выражение :-) поэтому в ответе третий абзац совсем непонятный

Comment: Поэтому я поправил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111263/discussion-between-grundy-and-noskill).

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но нет свободного времени...

Comment: дело не во времени, а в некорректности ответа ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ и в чате быстрее/удобнее разобраться чем в комментариях под ответом

Comment: Напишите корректный ответ сами.

Comment: Он уже написан :-) Примерно за три часа до твоего ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7):

jQuery **никак** не преобразует это в длину строки.

Метод [`.val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) возвращает просто строку.

Дальше работает [оператор логического отрицания](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)(**!**)

Данный оператор применяет к операнду абстрактный метод [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-toboolean), и инвертирует результат.

Как можно заметить из таблицы, для строк результат `ToBoolean` → *false*, если аргументом передается строка нулевой длины, после инвертирования получаем *true*.

Comment: Так что это за правило? То, что пустая строка вернет false я итак это описал в своем вопросе. Я не разбираюсь совсем в js, поэтому вопрос и задал

Comment: @Dred, обновил ответ

Answer (score 4):

Проверка идёт не на длину строки, а на то, пустая строка или нет (хотя по сути это одно и то же, но всё-таки).
При булевых операциях у JS есть определённые правила, по которым пустая строка считается `false`, а не пустая `true`.

Comment: Так что это за правило? То, что пустая строка вернет false я итак это описал в своем вопросе. Я не разбираюсь совсем в js, поэтому вопрос и задал